# Valgrind : How to use valgrind to detect memory leaks of native code on Android?

Tags: android, valgrind, android-testing, android-memory

How to use Valgrind for detecting the memory leaks in native code of an android application ? Does Valgrind support different devices and OS Versions? How good is its support for android emulator?

Answer (score 0):

The `README.android` file in the source distribution tells you how to use valgrind with Android, and gives a list of devices and Android versions which have been known to work in the past.